# Is a transit visa required for Ataturk Airport, Turkey (flying Islamabad to Olso)

Tags: istanbul, pakistani-citizens

I am planning to book a flight from Islamabad, Pakistan  to Oslo, Norway on Turkish Airlines. The flight is via Istanbul Atatürk airport.

I have a 10 hours and 30 minutes of stay at Atatürk airport. Do I need a transit visa for staying at airport terminal?

I have a Pakistani ordinary passport and Norway study visa.

Comment: Are you planning on staying in the airport for the ten hours, or do you want to leave the airport. I'm assuming the flights are booking on a single ticket, correct?

Comment: yeh i am planning to stay at airport.what a single ticket mean?

Comment: A single ticket just meets it's booked together (rather than booking two separate flights one from Islamabad to Istanbul and another from Istanbul to Oslo --with different reference numbers). I'm sure you have a single ticket (otherwise you'd know) and the linked question should have all the answers you need.

Comment: yeh i have a single ticket.. flight from islamabad to istanbul and istanbul to oslo is booked together.